# libtorrent custom messages between peers

Tags: chat, messaging, peer, libtorrent-rasterbar

I'm developing a custom torrent client using libtorrent-rasterbar, and I'm trying to implement a chat or custom-messaging between peers feature.

For example, I would like to know if my connected peer has finished the download (got all the pieces for the requested files). This way I want to notify a seeder that a peer got all pieces.

I've looked in the libtorrent-rasterbar documentation and found the "chat" extension; however, seems that it was removed, I didn't find traces of the "chat" feature in the latest 16.15 source, or at least I don't know how to use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.